# Vuetify Jest test for simple <v-data-table>

Tags: jestjs, vuetify.js

I can not write Jest test for my simple Component that has only one v-data-table Vuetify component. I try to get mounted component but get some errors " [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of undefined found in ---> ". I am a new one in Jest testing, so this problems drives me crazy ...

Here is my test file. Test component is taken from Vuetify doc page...

```
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import vuetify from 'vuetify';
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import Test from '../test';

Vue.use(vuetify);
Vue.use(Vuex);

describe('VehiclePassesList', () => {
  let wrapper = null;
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = mount(Test);
  });

  it('renders title', () => {
    console.log('PAGE: ', wrapper.html());
    expect(true).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of undefined

      12 | 
      13 |   it('renders title', () => {
    > 14 |     wrapper = mount(Test, { Vue });
         |               ^
      15 |     wrapper.vm.$nextTick();
      16 |     console.log('PAGE: ', wrapper.html());
      17 |     expect(true).toBe(true);

      at VueComponent.isMobile (node_modules/vuetify/dist/webpack:/Vuetify/src/components/VDataTable/VDataTable.ts:127:39)
      at Watcher.get (node_modules/vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.dev.js:4405:25)
`

Answer (score 4):

I stumbled upon the same issue for a couple of hours. After a while, I remembered the upgrade notes for Vuetify 2.x included an example on how to use Vuetify in unit tests and I realized that I was actually not doing that in my tests.

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/releases-and-migrations

If you check the unit tests section you can see that they create a new instance of Vuetify and then they pass it to the mount function:

```js
  beforeEach(() => {
    vuetify = new Vuetify(...)
  })

  it('should...', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(Component, {
      localVue,
      vuetify
    })
  })
```

I am not sure if this is helpful, but in my case, this seems to resolve the TypeError.

```
   TypeError: Cannot read property 'width' of undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also stub the `VDataTable` component :

```
const VDataTable = {
  props: ['items', 'loading'],
  template: '<div><slot :item="items[0]" name="item.name" /></div>'
}

shallowMount(MyComponentToTest, {
  stubs: {
    VDataTable
  }
})
```